# Australian Immigration 1945-present

Tags: 20th-century, australia, immigration

I have been wondering for a while and have always wanted to know about Australia's immigration history, my main question being:

1. Why has Australia accepted many migrants from 1945 to the present time?
2. Why is this still the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Post world war 2 immigration is considered the third of the major migration phases in Australia's post First Fleet in 1788, according to [the Melbourne Immigration Museum](https://museumvictoria.com.au/immigrationmuseum/whats-on/getting-in/)

> We focus on four periods: the gold rush days of the 1840s to 1900,
>   Federation to the end of the Second World War, then post-war to the
>   early seventies, and finally 1973 to the present day.

In 1945, Arthur Caldwell, Australian Minister for Immigration declared

> Australia wants, and will welcome, new healthy citizens who are
>   determined to become good Australians.

[The Migration heritage website also states](http://www.migrationheritage.nsw.gov.au/exhibition/objectsthroughtime-history/1945-1965/)

> After World War II ended in May 1945 Europe was in chaos. Germany was
>   crushed and the map of Europe was being carved up by the United States
>   and the Soviet Union. Western Europe was supported by the United
>   States while Eastern Europe was invaded by the Soviet Union. Migrants
>   began streaming out of Eastern Europe to places like Australia and the
>   United States to get away from the oppression in their homelands by
>   the Soviet Union. The Cold War between the United States and the
>   Soviet Union meant that nuclear war was a real threat and some people
>   saw Australia as a safe place to live.

[The Australian government says](http://www.australia.gov.au/about-australia/australian-story/changing-face-of-modern-australia-1950s-to-1970s)

> After the Second World War (1939–45) the Australian government
>   committed to a vigorous and sustained immigration program. The purpose
>   of this ambitious program was to meet labour shortages, protect
>   Australia from external threat and create prosperity. As a result,
>   from 1945 to 1975 Australia's population almost doubled from 7½
>   million to 13 million. About 3 million migrants and refugees arrived.
>
> This was a major break in policy. It was not the support for
>   immigration that was new, as Australia had been supporting immigration
>   since its inception and accepting refugees since the 1830s. Indeed,
>   Australian society was characterised by an expanded migration of
>   people, especially men from southern Europe, the Adriatic and the
>   Mediterranean in the years prior to the Second World War. This
>   migration had contributed to the making of modern Australia.
>
> However, in July 1947, the Australian Government entered into an
>   agreement with the new International Refugee Organisation to settle
>   displaced people from camps in Europe. The difference between a
>   migrant and a refugee is explained by UNHCR, the UN Refugee Agency:
>   Note that this was absolutely still under the White Australia policy,
>   so covered

Note this was still under the White Australia policy

> After the Second World War, the Australian government assumed that its
>   main source of immigrants would be Western Europe, but half the
>   immigrants in the 1950s and 60s were from the European continent. In
>   these two decades, Australia welcomed large groups of people, mostly
>   from Eastern Europe: Poland, Yugoslavia, Latvia, Lithuania, Estonia,
>   Ukraine, Czechoslovakia and Hungary. The overwhelming majority of
>   refugees were Eastern Europeans fleeing persecution in Soviet Bloc
>   countries.

Which ended in 1972 under Gough Whitlam

> From the mid-1970s the policy changed again. Mass migration programs
>   for British and European immigrants ended, the remnants of the White
>   Australia Policy were abolished, and arrivals began to come from
>   countries closer to Australia. At the same time political and
>   community support for immigration weakened and the catchcry 'Populate
>   of Perish' [sic!] lost favour.

Disclaimer: I'm an immigrant to Aus myself. Though phase 4.

Comment: thank you so much, your wealth of knowledge and help is unbelieveable. @Marakai

Comment: @james_nika You're welcome!

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'Populate or Perish'? 'Populate of Perish' does not make a lot of sense.

Comment: @SJuan76 You'll have to take that up with the webmasters there - I merely copy&pasted. Maybe I should add a [sic!] ?